# Repeated values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOqnL.jpg)

```
select  a.asi_hora , a.asi_fecha,a.asi_accion,t2.asi_fecha,t2.asi_hora,t2.asi_accion 
from asistencia a
join (select *from asistencia where asi_usu_id=(select usu_id from usuario where usu_cedula='0302222096') 
and asi_accion='Salida') as t2
where a.asi_usu_id=(select usu_id from usuario where usu_cedula='0302222096') 
and a.asi_accion='Entrada' and t2.asi_fecha=a.asi_fecha
and a.asi_hora<t2.asi_hora 
order by  a.asi_fecha
```

[HTML V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n69qW.jpg)

Hello, 
I have a problem when performing the following query. I want to visually eliminate marked "X" value, the case is as follows: 
The query is valid when there are no more than two bearings in one day, but when somebody scores four sometimes they cross more times and can not perform the calculation of the hours correctly any ideas?

Comment: Please paste your code / query here

Comment: select  a.asi_hora , a.asi_fecha,a.asi_accion,t2.asi_fecha,t2.asi_hora,t2.asi_accion from asistencia a
join (select *from asistencia where asi_usu_id=(select usu_id from usuario where usu_cedula='0302222096') 
and asi_accion='Salida') as t2
where a.asi_usu_id=(select usu_id from usuario where usu_cedula='0302222096') 
and a.asi_accion='Entrada' and t2.asi_fecha=a.asi_fecha
and a.asi_hora<t2.asi_hora 
order by  a.asi_fecha

Answer (score 1):

Its very complex query, which is undoubtedly nobody recommends to apply on any project. In your query repeating rows is due to joining "asistencia" colums.